# Writing a custom protocol handler portable on Firefox, Chrome and IE running on Window

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, firefox, protocol-handler

I am writing a protocol handler to launch a java application, calling a command like java -jar myApp '%1'. Currently I have implemented it for Chrome and it looks work correcly. Unfortunately I don't have the same behavior for Firefox and IE (weird uh?! X-D )

Here my implementation.

The protocol is named dgh.
During the first installation my application set the following keys in windows registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dgh]
@="URL:DgHome  Protocol"
"URL Procol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dgh\DefaultIcon]
@="C:/DGHOME/IPlusConf.exe,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dgh\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dgh\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dgh\shell\open\command]
@="java -jar C:/DGHOME/Pch/lib/pch.teleconsulto.jar \"%1\""
```

On chrome this is enough.
On Firefox, I had to add some configurations in *about:config*.Following MDN on Firefox I set the following

```
network.protocol-handler.expose.dgh;true
network.protocol-handler.external.dgh;true
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.dgh;false
```

In this way firefox at least ask to me if I want launch an application and ask to me to select one: **I don't want that, I would it call the command I set and advise the first time the user about that:**

On IE nothing happens, it says can't open the web page reference by my link.

Here a set of link I used as test

```
<a href="dgh://call/open?id='kit1.teleconsulto'">Open call to kit1.teleconsulto</a>
<a href="dgh://teleconsult/start?id='kit1.teleconsulto'">
   Open teleconsult to kit1.teleconsulto</a>
<a href="dgh://call/close">Close call</a>
<a href="dgh://call/end">Close client</a>
<a href="dgh://stethoscope/start">On Phonendo</a>
```

here some references:
[Installing and Registering Protocol Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28VS.85%29.aspx

I hope sincerely someone can help me

Comment: I know that what I am going to write is not professional and absolutely not polite however I have to do :
there is nobody that even imagine how to solve that??! sob :'( :'( :'(

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that the you're calling the jar directly in your protocol handler. You need to invoke java.exe with the -jar parameter

Your registry key should look like this

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\digitalmgi]
@="URL:digitalmgi protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\digitalmgi\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\myCoolIcon.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\digitalmgi\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\digitalmgi\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\digitalmgi\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe\" -jar \"C:\\MyPath\\myJar.jar\" \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have taken the approach of Registering in the system's registry but, If you are willing to take a different approach then, there is a Generic solution available at [Generic-Protocol-Handler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545083/Custom-HyperLinks-Using-a-Generic-Protocol-Handler) which surely will address the Cross Browser compatibility issue.

Please Mark this as Answer, if it helps :)