# Can Chrome Apps register protocol handlers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I have a working JS Apps that correctly register a protocol handler when been served as a web site. After packing it as a chrome app, protocol handler is not been registered (bitcoin:). Also, there doesn't seems to be nothing related in `manifiest.json` to protocol handlers.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension : Custom Protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836554/chrome-extension-custom-protocol)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Chrome apps and extensions are very different. We make an extension first, and protocols handlers worked OK, using the standard javascript API to register them.

Comment: JSTorrent registers for magnet: handling. It uses jstorrent.com to register and then sends things to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the only solution is to register a protocol handler from a regular web site. You can then use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to send a message to the application's background page, where it can open a window or take some other action.